# How to implement a survival function PDF?

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, random-walk, levy-distribution

I'm trying to generate a set of points whose separations are given by a Lévy flight. A source that I have (Peebles 1993) says that the process goes as

> Starting from a [point] in space, place the next [point] in a randomly chosen direction at a distance $\delta$ drawn from the probability distribution

$p(>\delta) = \begin{cases} (\delta_0/\delta)^D & \delta \geq \delta_0\\
                               1 & \delta < \delta_0\end{cases}$

I want to implement this, and what I'd like out in the end is a vector of randomly drawn $\delta$. I don't understand how I can "draw" from something that is expressed in this way, though... this takes the form of a survival function, which as I understand is more closely understood as a CDF than a PDF. So, how do I understand "drawing" from this distribution? In particular, I don't really understand why the input arguement to $p$ is $>\delta$. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

This is the survival function of a [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).

There are varies ways of drawing samples from it, for example in R or Python there are multiple packages contains the Pareto random sampler. You can find the packages by, for example searching on google "random sampler Pareto R"